# Including a multi page PostScript document into latex

Tags: pstricks, ps

Is there a hack to include a multi page Postscript document into a a final `ps` document through `latex` and `dvips`? Essentially what I have is a `ps` article that i need in my `latex>dvi>ps` document.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you convert the PS document to PDF?  (eg with Distiller, or OSX Preview, or GhostScript etc...)  If so you could then look at the capabilities of `pdfpages` to include all or part of your document.

Comment: well i tried \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{file.pdf} but all i get when compile is a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `dvips` driver (via the `psfile` special) does not support multipage PS inclusion. You have to go the PDF route using `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex`. This requires you to convert the multipage PS into multipage PDF first. Then you can use one of the `graphicx` or `pdfpages` packages to select the pages to be embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `ps` file into a `pdf` with `ps2pdf` and then you can create single `eps`-files of the pages. Save the following script as `pdf2eps` and then you can say `pdf2eps 2 <file>` which will create an `eps` of page 2:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: pdf2eps,v 0.01 2005/10/28 00:55:46 Herbert Voss Exp $
# Convert PDF to encapsulated PostScript.
# usage:
# pdf2eps <picture number> <pdf file without ext>

pdfcrop $2.pdf
pdftops -f $1 -l $1 -eps "$2-crop.pdf" 
rm  "$2-crop.pdf"
mv  "$2-crop.eps" $2.eps
```

or simply use the line `pdftops`